# Suggested tags not being updated on question edition

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-tags

I started writing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22832176/1469208) and put entire paragraph with relation to Yii Framework. I was suggested to include [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [yii](/questions/tagged/yii). After a while (without actually asking the question), I decided, that this could be taken as too localized and removed the entire paragraph.

Question now contains not even a trace of Yii, but before submitting it, tag [yii](/questions/tagged/yii) wasn't removed from the  "suggested tags" list. I waited over two minutes, without changing even a letter in the question, but tag was not removed.

Is it a bug or wanted behavior?

When asking this or many other question, I noticed, that suggested tags are being updated as user writes the question. They shifts their order. But it seems, that are not removed.

Comment: Looks like the suggested tags refresh only after change of title.